# JLabel.setText is working in a strange way

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm trying to create a copy of the game Stratego and and I'm having some trouble setting the text in a label. The code might explain it better. The supposed "." is in the corrdinates "3C", which corresponds to BoardSquares[2][2], but if I do a print of BoardSquares[2][2].getText() it will print out the "S" in the console, but not in the JLabel. Any idea why?

There is a link to a image to show the gridlayout with the JLabels. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGcDZ.png

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int totalP = 40;
    Board cb = new Board();
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Stratego");
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            f.add(cb.getGui());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
            // in order display the components within it
            f.pack();
            // ensures the minimum size is enforced.
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
            f.setVisible(true);

        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    do {
        System.out.println("peça a mover");
        System.out.println("insira a linha da peça a mover ");
        int a = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("insira a coluna da peça a mover");
        int b = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("insira a linha para onde a quer mover ");
        int c = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("insira a coluna para onde a quer mover ");
        int d = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println(cb.canMoveTo(a, b, c, d));
        System.out.println(BoardSquares[b - 1][a - 1].getText());
        System.out.println(BoardSquares[d - 1][c - 1].getText());
        if (cb.canMoveTo(a, b, c, d)) {
            
            BoardSquares[d - 1][c - 1].setText(BoardSquares[b - 1][a - 1].getText());
            // setting the text with an "S" that was on the BoardSquare[b-1][a-1]
            // the BoardSquares[d-1][c-1].getText() will give the correct value
            // but in the gridlayout with the JLabels it will have a "." instead of and "S"
            BoardSquares[b - 1][a - 1].setText("altered");
            f.add(cb.getGui());

        }

    } while (totalP > 0);
```

Comment: Your do-loop is executing on the main thread, not the event thread. And if it were on the event thread, it would block that thread. You need to use a Timer instead.

Comment: a timer? how so? I'm still kinda new to programing so i don't understand a whole lot of the terms

Comment: @JoãoFolgado Then you should start by looking [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)